# Correct container technolgy on azure for long running service

Tags: azure, docker, azure-app-service-envrmnt, azure-container-instances

I want to run a docker container which hosts a server which is going to be long running (e.g. 24x7).

Initially I looked at Azure Container Instances (ACI) and whilst these seems to fit the bill perfectly I've been advised they're not designed for long running containers, also they can prove to be quite expensive to run all the time compared to a basic VM.

So I've been looking at what else I should run this as:

- AKS - Seems overkill for just one docker container
- App Service for containers - my container doesn't have an http endpoint so I believe I will have issues with things like health checks
- VM - this seems all a bit manual as I'd really like not to deal with VM maintenance and I'm also unsure I can use CI/CD techniques to build / spin up-down / do releases on a VM image (we're using terraform to deploy infra).

Are there any best practise guides on this, I've tried searching but I'm not finding anything relevant, I'm assuming I'm missing some key term to get going with this!

TIA

Answer (score 0):

ACI is not designed for long-running (uninterrupted) processes have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65689974/azure-container-instance-restarting-once-in-a-while-for-no-apparent-reason/67162483#67162483)

Recommendation is to use AKS where you can fully manage lifecycle of your machines or just use VMs